# how many ways are there to distribute 10white and 10black balls into 20 distinct boxes so that at most one box is empty

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning

**Question:** how many ways are there to distribute 10white and 10black balls into 20 distinct boxes so that at most one box is empty.

[image]

[image]

I understand case-1. But I cannot understand a part of answer of case-2.

The answer of case-2 is $\binom{20}{1}\binom{19}{1}[\binom{18}{8}+\binom{18}{8}+\binom{18}{9}]$

$\binom{20}{1} \rightarrow$ choose one empty box.

$\binom{19}{1}\rightarrow$ choose one box containing 2balls.

But how to write $[\binom{18}{8}+\binom{18}{8}+\binom{18}{9}]$? Please explain the part. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one empty box, and therefore a box that contains two balls. The unlucky box can be chosen in $\binom{20}{1}$ ways, and for each choice the lucky box can be chosen in $\binom{19}{1}$ ways.

Suppose now that we have chosen the empty box and the lucky box. There are $3$ cases: (i) the lucky box contains two whites; (ii) the lucky box contains two blacks; (iii) the lucky box gets a black and a white.

For Case (i), we **choose** $8$ boxes from the remaining $18$ to get the remaining $8$ whites. This can be done in $\binom{18}{8}$ ways.

Obviously Case (ii) has the same number of possibilities as Case (i).

For Case (iii), we need to choose $9$ places from the remaining $18$ for the whites.

Comment: Let's consider case(i). I have 18 remaining boxes and 10 black, 8white balls(I placed 2white balls into the lucky box). And also, I placed these 10black balls into remaining 18boxes. $\binom{18}{8}$ shows us how to distribute 8 remaining white balls into 18 boxes. Right?

Comment: I do not think that is a good way of trying to visualize. There are $18$ boxes left. There are $\binom{18}{8}$ ways of placing the whites. For each of these ways, there is $1$ way of placing the blacks. Thus the count is $\binom{18}{8}(1)$. Alternately, you could place the blacks first, there are $\binom{18}{10}$ ways of doing it, and now where the whites go is determined. That gives the same answer, since $\binom{18}{10}=\binom{18}{8}$.